# modules installed in python 2.6 not works in python 2.7

Tags: python

I have installed python2.6, and I now installed python 2.7.

My problem is that the modules (numpy for example) installed in python 2.6 not works in Python 2.7, why?

Answer (score 1):

Packages like `numpy` contain binary modules these are compiled specifically for a given version of Python and will not work with any other version of Python. Modules are installed in Python version specific directories and must be installed for each installed version of Python.

You will need to install `numpy` for Python 2.7.